# How to delete Area 51 account

Tags: feature-request, area-51, user-accounts

I have an Area 51 account that I have never used, and I want to delete it. Shouldn't there be a delete button on my profile page?

On other sites, you can self-delete if you haven't voted or asked a question more than once. Why not on the Area 51 site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly because Area 51 development is largely on hold right now while we work on the next generation site proposal process.

If you edit the "about me" section of your Area 51 profile to confirm the deletion request, I'll take care of it for you.

Comment: Ah, I see. I edited my about me section. Thank you!

Comment: @woz All done. :)

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Next gen work isn't completed. To delete your A51 profile, edit it to say "delete me" in the About Me section and email us. If you already did that and changed your mind, remove "delete me" from the profile.