# how long does it usually take to delete my Area51 account and private beta account

Tags: support, area-51, user-accounts, private-beta

I am in need of deleting my Area51 account, I have read a similar post about this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157247/how-to-delete-area-51-account), but my situation is slightly different - I have used it and are member of a private beta (Space Exploration).  I have sent in an email request and updated my profiles for those pages to say "please delete me", is there any more I need to do?

How long does it take to delete the profiles of both?

(The account deletion seems to be very different on Area51 and private beta than other sites).

Comment: How long has it *been*? The site is still in private beta...

Comment: The main thing I am in need of information of is account deletion from Area51

Comment: Account deletion is manual, you'll probably have to wait until all the people in NY wake up and come to work. Though I'm a bit surprised why the deletion of an Area 51 account would be so urgent

Comment: @MadScientist ah yes, thank you for that - makes sense, I sometimes lose track of timezones, (I am in UTC +10).  The account deletion is not terribly urgent per se, I am just curious as to how long it takes - and your comment pretty well answered it nicely.

Comment: No, there is nothing else you need to do. Wait for the unicor- I mean, developers, to delete it for you.

Comment: @Doorknob lol, I see what you almost did there!  My request has been actioned - that was nice and quick!