# How to delete my Area 51 user account?

Tags: support, area-51, profile-page, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I have accounts in Stack Overflow, Programmers, Unix & Linux and Area 51. I don't want to continue my Area 51 account, so I planned to delete my Area 51 account. I have performed the following steps to delete my account, but I couldn't!

### Case 1

> If your account has votes or posts do the following steps:
>
> 1. Edit the "About Me" section of your profile to say “please delete me”.
> 2. Contact the SE support to request deletion.

I edited my "About Me" section to "please delete me". When I contacted SE Support to delete my account, I couldn't make a request. I am getting the following error:

```
This operation is incomplete. please do it in main site.
```

For deleting Area 51 account, when I do it main site, in link for deletion column I gave the Area 51 link. It says that:

```
it is not valid link!
```

### Case 2

> If the account has not interacted with the site yet (votes or posts), click on the delete button on your user page next to the edit link.

I am not eligible for this case!

Then how to delete my Area 51 account? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm looking into this now.  To be clear, you get this when trying to submit the contact form?

Comment: ya! after filling all field, when i am try to submit i couldn't!

Comment: Okay, clear - yeah, reproduced. More an unintended consequence than a bug, but - devs informed.

Comment: I also went ahead and took care of your request.

Comment: @TimPost My Area 51 got deleted. But i didn't Send them a mail! i dont know how! but thank you!!

Comment: @Sathish think it's pretty clear Tim did it himself, the answer he gave is meant for other people who want to do the same thing.

Comment: @TimPost - It's 2017, and still can't delete Area51 profile without following below answer. Between, mine is still to be deleted.

Comment: The procedure is a bit different since this question was answered; the current procedure is in [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete Area 51 account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157247/how-to-delete-area-51-account) or  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324433/282094

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is ... not working as it should be. A quick workaround would be to follow the steps to the point where you confirm ownership of your profile by placing 'delete me' somewhere in the 'about me' section of your profile, and then e-mailing `team@stackexchange.com` directly with:

**Subject**:

> Please delete my Area 51 profile

Make *certain* that you put a link to your profile in the body, and optionally give us any feedback that you think is appropriate as to why you wish to leave Area 51. Not using it anymore is a perfectly fine reason.

The reason for this is, Area 51 discussion zone is technically considered to be a child meta site, and we want this type of request coming from the *main* site, or the support workflow breaks down some. However, since the *parent* Area 51 site is like nothing else in our network, the code there is ... different, so the code with the new contact form didn't go in there, thus we redirect to Discuss.Area51.

I'm not sure what will be done to fix that, or when, but there's at least a workaround. I'll see about getting instructions found elsewhere updated if this isn't a quick fix.

Comment: [It's changed for the worse within the last 4.5 years of posting this.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324433/area-51-accounts-cant-be-deleted-by-the-user-but-the-system-prevents-users-fro?noredirect=1)