# Area 51 accounts can't be deleted by the user, but the system prevents users from using the contact form

Tags: bug, area-51, deleted-accounts, 404-not-found

If a user wants to delete their Area 51 account, it's not possible to do so through the normal settings. The [account deletion FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) says to contact SE if one wants their Area 51 account deleted.

When I click the "contact us" link at the bottom of the Area 51 homepage, I get directed to https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/contact, i.e. the Area 51 Discussions contact form. Area 51 Discussions is based off the "modern" SE code base.

From there, if one tries to choose the option "I need to delete my user profile", the system shows a dialog box with an option to click "Continue" or close the box. If I close the box, the dropdown option is cleared. This is intended behavior on normal SE sites where one can delete their own account, but on Area 51 it doesn't make sense since one can't delete their own account.

Additionally, if one clicks the "Continue" button, they are then redirected to https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/delete/current, which leads to a 404 error.

This creates a **very confusing** scenario for one who wants to delete their Area 51 account: they can't do so through the normal account settings, then the FAQ says to contact SE, then the contact form doesn't allow one to choose the option for deletion and directs them to a non-existent page instead.

The solutions here would be to remove the restriction against choosing the "I need to delete my user profile" option on the Area 51 Discussions contact form, or to make the Continue button not direct the user anywhere, but just close the box and leave the option set.

Comment: Ah! I have had exactly this problem. I subscribed by accident and for the last three years or so I've been trying to delete my account but with no success. I am stuck with an account I don't need as I have never proposed a new site.

Comment: @Mari-LouA [How to delete my Area 51 user account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237691/how-to-delete-my-area-51-user-account)

Comment: Another option is to just remove that option from the dropdown if the site is Area 51 and not muck up the code adding exceptions for an old codebase in the JavaScript itself. ;) There's no point in having a separate option there if it doesn't have any special functionality outside of the "other" option. As an aside (and I don't know why) most of our Area 51 deletion requests actually come in from here on Meta via the other option anyways.

Comment: @animuson Probably because they try and fail to use the Area 51 contact form, then go to some other site (e.g. Meta) and request it from there.

Comment: FYI, the FAQ was just [edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/7979/89) to advise users to use the "other" option instead of "I need to delete my account". CC: @animuson