# Is a user deleted in one Stack Exchange deleted in all of them?

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts

I'm considering deleting my profile on one site, but want to know something before I proceed. Is a user deleted in one Stack Exchange site deleted in all of them? Can I delete only the one profile?

Comment: @gnat I followed those questions, but (at least) in area51 the option "Delete my account" isn't there, not just that, you have to go to "contact us" and select an option to delete that leads to a "page not found". My only choice was to write an email. Is this information useful to add here? Should I accept "How can I delete my account?"?

Comment: The question I linked, the FAQ on deleting accounts, also explains how to delete your Area 51 account.

Comment: this is covered in another duplicate: [Area 51 accounts can't be deleted by the user, but the system prevents users from using the contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324433/165773)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog sorry I missed that. I'll accept the duplicate answers, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is a user deleted in one stackexchange site deleted in all of them?

No, usually that's not the case.

In order for a user account to be nuked network wide, that user must have shown notoriously bad behavior over all their SE accounts. Furthermore, the deletion would have to be done by SE staff (community managers) and not community-elected site moderators.